# Applying callback design pattern with Node-JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, return-value

I believe I understand the design pattern of a callback in a basic form. I however don't know if and how to apply this design pattern to this more complex situation.

I'm writing a set of JavaScript functions to be used server-side. These functions have to return data which is fetched from a local database if possible, from an external API otherwise. What I want to do is, in summary:

```js
//dataProvider.js
function DataProvider (dbCredentials, apiCredentials) {
  DB = require('./dbStuff');
  API = require('./apiStuff');
  this.db = new DB(dbCredentials);
  this.api = new API(apiCredentials);
  
  this.getSpecificData = getSpecificDataWrapper(this.db, this.api);
}

function getSpecificDataWrapper(db, api) {
  return function (extraQueryInfo) {
    var result = db.genericGetFunc(specificDBQuery);
    if (!satisfyingResult(result)) {
      result = api.genericGetFunc(specificAPIQuery);
    return result;
  }
}
```

When calling this function from the main `app.js` file, I would like to do this as `dataProviderInstance.getSpecificData(extraQueryInfo)`. Right now I have a similar structure set up for the database and api functions which execute the queries. But as these queries take time, the `getSpecificData` always returns undefined.

As code is in different files, the usage of so many call backs would make me go insane. So how do I use callbacks with these two or more level deep function calls?

Comment: Have you tried using a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to go for promises instead of callbacks.
The problem with callbacks is that it can become very messy at the end.

A really nice solution for your problem would be something like this.

```js
//dataProvider.js
function DataProvider (dbCredentials, apiCredentials) {
  DB = require('./dbStuff');
  API = require('./apiStuff');
  this.db = new DB(dbCredentials);
  this.api = new API(apiCredentials);
  
  this.getSpecificData = getSpecificDataWrapper(this.db, this.api);
}

function getSpecificDataWrapper(db, api) {
  
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    
    //I Assume that if this is an async operation, either receives a callback
    //function or returns a promise.
    db.genericGetFunc(specificDBQuery)
      .then (function(result) {
        if (satisfyingResult(result)) resolve(result)
        
        // Again, I Assume that if this is an async operation, either receives a
        //callback function or returns a promise.
        else return api.genericGetFunc(specificAPIQuery);
      })
      .then (function(result){
        resolve(result);
      })
      .catch (function(err){
        reject(err);
      })
    
  });
  
}
```

So the getSpecificData function will return a promise...you just need to chain with then to wait for result

```
DataProvider.getSpecificData().then(function(result){
  //result will have your data
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also use `Promise.promisify(function)` instead of wrapping your function with `new Promise()` if you are using bluebird implementation of promise. http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/anti-patterns.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DB and API modules also use the callback pattern,
then you should extend the getSpecificData() method with a 
callback parameter. This callback method is then called with
a satisfying result of DB or otherwise with the result of API:

```
function getSpecificDataWrapper(db, api) {
  return function (extraQueryInfo, callback) {
    db.genericGetFunc(specificDBQuery, function(result){
      if(satisfyingResult(result)){
        callback(result);
      }
      else {
        api.genericGetFunc(specificAPIQuery, function(result){
          callback(result);
        });
      }
    });
  }
}

dataProviderInstance.getSpecificData(extraQueryInfo, function(result){
  // handle result here
});
```